# How to debug Shell command after customization

Tags: linux, macos, shell, debugging, zsh

I spent some time on customizing my configuration like [many people do](http://dotfiles.github.io/). Basically I symlink all my dotfiles (.zshrc, .vimrc,...) from a git repository then I changed a lot of stuff.

I'm on Mac OS X and my configuration works very well. However when I use the same dotfiles on Linux (Ubuntu) I get some differences. Most of them are minor differences but on is VERY annoying.

I use **ZSH** and **prezto**

When I do `cd` I get this message

```
20:17 ~ ❯ cd Projects                                                                                            

script: invalid option -- 'G'

Usage:
 script [options] [file]

Options:
 -a, --append            append the output
 -c, --command <command> run command rather than interactive shell
 -r, --return            return exit code of the child process
 -f, --flush             run flush after each write
     --force             use output file even when it is a link
 -q, --quiet             be quiet
 -t, --timing[=<file>]   output timing data to stderr (or to FILE)
 -V, --version           output version information and exit
 -h, --help              display this help and exit
```

The type command (`type cd`) give me

```
    cd is an alias for nocorrect cd
    cd is a shell builtin
```

I am posting here to know if anyone know a way to debug this kind of error. The error message isn't very clear and I don't know what and where to look for.

Any ideas ?

Most of my configuration comes from many other people's configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can start `zsh` with the parameter `-x` for debugging. This will echo any line of shell code run by this shell before it is executed. This helps locating where in your configuration things go awry.

---

In this case you get an error message from `script` because it does not have an option `'G'` in addition to a lists of all available options (try and compare `script -G`). Command line tools often differ quite a bit between different Unix derivatives, that includes number and meaning of command line options. Compare `man script` between your platforms.

As `cd` is an alias for `nocorrect cd`, `nocorrect` seems to be the most likely culprit. To check, run `unalias cd`. If the problem goes away, do a `type nocorrect` and go from there.

If the problem persists search your configuration for `chpwd` (this may be either a function definition or a line like `add-zsh-hook chpwd SOMETHING`).

Comment: Thanks for all the advice ! `zsh -x` showed me that after cd there some mysterious `script -q /dev/null ls -G .` I will try to search something about this

Answer (score 1):

*Solution for Ubuntu*:

find the script where this code line is located
`script -q /dev/null ls -G .` and change it to `script -q /dev/null -c 'ls -G .'`

In my case it was `prompt_paulmillr_setup`, but it depends on which ZSH extension you use.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the exact same problem with the same file. I figured it out after using zsh -x.
Thanks again