# Why would my ZSH scripts print out all history, but on Ubuntu only?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've cloned a very popular set of dotfiles for ZSH, you can see the repo here: https://github.com/aronchick/dotfiles

On MacOS X (Yosemite) it works great, exactly as expected. On Ubuntu, on the other hand, it repeats my entire history before it executes each command. For example:

On Mac:

```
# aronchick at mbp.com in ~/Public [10:22:01]
$ ls
Drop Box

# aronchick at mbp.com in ~/Public [10:22:03]
$
```

On Ubuntu 14.04:

```
# aronchick at ub.mbp.com in ~/Public [10:23:35]
$ ls -la

[100+ lines of history]
 git submodule init
 ls -la
 cd ..
 ls -la
 cd ..
 ls
 ls -la total 8
drwxr-x---  2 aronchick wheel 4096 Mar 17 10:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 aronchick wheel 4096 Mar 17 10:23 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 aronchick wheel    0 Mar 17 10:23 DropBox

# aronchick at ub.mbp.com in ~/Public [10:23:39]
$
```

Any idea what would cause this disparity between the two platforms? I know they're exactly the same, I've cloned both from the exact same repo.

Comment: Are both running the same zsh version?  `zsh --version`?

Comment: Yep - both running zsh 5.0.5

Comment: I'd check your aliases and user defined functions to see if something is overriding `ls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I discovered what the issue is, but not how to solve it (or why it was done this way).

First, thanks to this ([How to debug Shell command after customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837656/how-to-debug-shell-command-after-customization)) stack overflow question, I discovered you can execute `zsh -x` and have it print out literally every line of every piece of your shell before executing. Ultimately, it came down to this line:

```
function set_running_app {
  echo -ne "\e]1; $PWD:t:$(history $HISTCMD | cut -b7- ) \a"
}
```

I have no idea what this is intended to do (it appears it's trying to print out a subset of the previous command as part of the command line, but why it is just starting at byte 7 is beyond me), and it doesn't appear to be used anywhere else. I also don't know why it works (?) on the Mac by not on the Ubuntu box.

Commenting this out solved it.

Comment: The issue seems to be that `history $HISTCMD` is returning one item on MacOS X but multiple item under Ubuntu.  Could you verify that for me?  `$HISTCMD` should contain a number corresponding to your current history entry.

Comment: Just checked it, and it seems like it's retrieving a list of both. WEIRD!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem -- this same command can be found in [ze-best-zsh-config](https://github.com/spicycode/ze-best-zsh-config). The Ubuntu behavior also happens on OS X if you are running `screen`.

Expanding on aronchick's answer, I think there are 2 things going on here.

`"\e[1; ... \a"` is an [xterm escape sequence](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#toc4) to set the titlebar.  I think the core issue is that this escape sequence is somehow not processed correctly in some environments (eg. Ubuntu or OS X under `screen`) so it renders to the terminal instead.  I'm not sure what the exact issue is here, though, the only real solution I've found is to remove the `set_running_app` function entirely.

On my system (running [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)) I found an additional wrinkle, which is that the `history` command is actually aliased to `fc -l 1`.  I think this may be a semi-standard alias under zsh, but one effect is that it **always** prints out the full history, even when passed a history entry number.  (`$HISTCMD` returns the last entry number in the history, so `history $HISTCMD` would normally return just the last history entry.  The `| cut -b7-` part removes the entry number itself, leaving just the command.)

So presumably this command is intended to set the titlebar to the currently executing program, eg. if you run `vi` the titlebar will say "vi" while it's running.  I can't figure out what the `$PWD:t:` part is for, though.  It looks like maybe it was a zsh expansion that got corrupted or something.